# Почему это создает переменную?

Tags: c++

Данный код создает переменную s типа int

```
int(s);
```

Comment: а что вы хотели?

Comment: я ожидал compilation error, получается что мы передаем конструктору имя переменной которая не определена. с какого c++ это работает?

Comment: скобки всегда можете ставить вокруг выражения, это ничего не меняет, но это не инициализация.

Comment: Хочешь инициализацию, используй int{s}.

Answer (score 5):

Это тоже самое что `int s;` Скобки допускаются, а иногда они меняют значение:

```
int * a [10];     // declare a as array 10 of pointer to int (thanks to https://cdecl.org/ and English SO)
int ( * b ) [10]; // declare b as pointer to array 10 of int
```

А также скобки применяютя при объявлении указателя на функцию. Интересно, что в этом случае они не обязательны.

```
int (*b)(int); // declare b as pointer to function (int) returning int
```